# I dont understand how to get in methods in my class in JAVA

Tags: java

I don't understand why I get a compilation error, I hope someone can help out here. I would appreciate it a lot. I'm trying to make a system for a lot of cars.

```
public class Car {
    //Instance Variables
    String make;
    String model;
    int year;
    boolean isNew;
    double miles;
    String owner;
    public void sell (String newOwner) {
        owner=newOwner;
        if (isNew){
            isNew=false;
        }
    }
    public boolean isOld() {
        int thisYear=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        if (thisYear-year > 10) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } 
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car myCar = new Car(); //myCar is a variable and new the keyword
    myCar.make = "Audi";
    myCar.model = "A4";
    myCar.year =2014;
    myCar.isNew=true;
    myCar.miles =0;
    myCar.owner ="Jeyson";
    boolean isMyCarOld = myCar.isOld();
    myCar.sell("John Doe");
    System.out.println("Car owned by" + myCar.owner);
}
```

Comment: it seems that the main methos is outside your class and this is not correct :)

Comment: just replace the last `}` before the main method and put is after the `}` of the main methos `}}`

Comment: If you indented your code properly it would be clear where the errors were.

Comment: As you are new user here, so let me tell you one thing, if an answer solves your problem then you should mark it as accepted. To accept an answer just click on the right tick mark sign on left side of answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write `main` method out side of your class. It should be written inside class.

The following code should work,

```
public class Car {
    //Instance Variables
    String make;
    String model;
    int year;
    boolean isNew;
    double miles;
    String owner;
    public void sell (String newOwner) {
        owner=newOwner;
        if (isNew){
            isNew=false;
        }
    }
    public boolean isOld() {
        int thisYear=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        if (thisYear-year > 10){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Car myCar = new Car(); //myCar is a variable and new the keyword
        myCar.make = "Audi";
        myCar.model = "A4";
        myCar.year =2014;
        myCar.isNew=true;
        myCar.miles =0;
        myCar.owner ="Jeyson";
        boolean isMyCarOld = myCar.isOld();
        myCar.sell("John Doe");
        System.out.println("Car owned by" + myCar.owner);
    }
}
```